# ASP.NET - Integrate Twitter in FaceBook Style

Tags: asp.net, facebook, twitter

I have a requirement of integrating Social Login for FB and Twitter in one of our applications.

We have successfully integrated both of them.

Unfortunately, we are facing problem with Twitter Integration as we used some DLL's for Twitter authentication.

The problem is that the Firewall is restricting the code to access internet on the server and so Twitter authentication is not working. However, there is no problem with Facebook as it is kind of client side mechanism where in it uses client's internet.

Is there any solution for twitter which works similar to Facebook integration?

Thank you.
Prawin

Comment: you can implement your selft withour using dll read this https://blog.twitter.com/2013/changes-to-sign-in-with-twitter

Comment: Hi GujjuDeveloper, Thanks for your response. Could you please let me know if there is any SDK for implementing the same?